# Can I prevent an Android app from getting killed if I'm using the location permission and user revokes it while app is open?

Tags: android, permissions, location

If I am getting location information and the user goes into settings and revokes the location permission for the app, the app gets killed immediately.

Is it possible to catch this event and deal with it instead of just getting killed?

Comment: To the guy who voted this "too broad": Why don't you speak up and describe what you mean? What's too broad about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use try - catch, but the recommended way is checking permissions:

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

     // Access is allowed - do it!
 }
```

PS As far as I know, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION assumes ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, so you probably don't need an additional test for it.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I'm talking about when I'm already getting location information and the user revokes the permission (implying that the user previously allowed the permission when the app started). The one-time check does not help.